# How can I count my Country total from GeoIP in python

Tags: python

I want to know how can I count the total of listed countries from GeoIP code. I have made a code but it shows only half of the total, for instance it shows that China appears 65 times, but there are more than that. This is my code

```
import re
import string

frequency = {}
document_text = open('/Users/mani/Desktop/finalgeoip.txt', 'r')
text_string = document_text.read().lower()
match_pattern = re.findall(r'[a-z]{3,15}', text_string)

for word in match_pattern:
    count = frequency.get(word, 0)
    frequency[word] = count + 1

frequency_list = frequency.keys()

for words in frequency_list:
    print words, frequency[words]
```

This is my output

```
China                         1
China                         2
Ireland                       1
China                         3
Moldova, Republic of          1
Japan                         1
China                         1
China                         2
Brazil                        1
```

So there are China 1, China 2, China 2
So I want the output:

```
China     5
```

But my code just count the string total

This is my log file

```
2017-04-18 00:00:00 Local7.Info 10.82.12.3  date=2017-04-17 time=23:59:59 devname=IDS-DC14-001 devid=FGT90D3Z15018997 logid=1059028704 type=utm subtype=app-ctrl eventtype=app-ctrl-all level=information vd=root appid=16206 user="" srcip=180.16.170.129 srcport=0 srcintf="wan1" dstip=116.238.73.58 dstport=771 dstintf="wan1" profiletype="applist" proto=1 service="icmp/3/3" policyid=3 sessionid=41936599 applist="sniffer-profile" appcat="Network.Service" app="ICMP" action=pass msg="Network.Service: ICMP," apprisk=elevated
2017-04-18 00:00:00 Local7.Info 10.82.12.3  date=2017-04-17 time=23:59:59 devname=IDS-DC14-001 devid=FGT90D3Z15018997 logid=1059028704 type=utm subtype=app-ctrl eventtype=app-ctrl-all level=information vd=root appid=27946 user="" srcip=10.80.10.249 srcport=9207 srcintf="wan1" dstip=208.91.112.196 dstport=53 dstintf="wan1" profiletype="applist" proto=17 service="DNS" policyid=3 sessionid=41936600 applist="sniffer-profile" appcat="Cloud.IT" app="Fortiguard.Search" action=pass msg="Cloud.IT: Fortiguard.Search," apprisk=medium
```

Comment: Again, what does the input look like. Just copy like 5-10 lines of your input and provide the desired output when pretending there are only those 5-10 lines.

Comment: @Igle but that is a log file, and the file is too big. I took the ip address, country, and count of the ip address. That ip address count each locations of the countries

Comment: So what's the problem with just taking a small part of this log file as example and put that in your question? SO works best when you can provide a good example, so that everyone gets the question right.

Comment: @Igle I have updated the log file, from the log file, I print the destination ip and take the  location and based on the location count the total ip addresses like Chiina 2, China 4.

Comment: Okay, from this log I can not see how you parse a country name because there are no names in it. Furthermore, your regex matches every part of your log consisting from 3 to 15 lower case letters. Therefore your code you posted can't print one of the countries at all. Is there more code you didn't put here?

Comment: @Igle I used GeoIP code for detecting the location of the ip address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `collections.Counter`
Assuming `match_pattern` is a List of IP's you want to count.

```
import collections 
c = collections.Counter()
for ip in match_pattern: 
    c.update(get_country_from_ip(ip))

print(c)
```